# Toggle MVC view controls based on user claims

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc

I have application written in .net core MVC, c#. 
Once the user logs in to the application, after successful authentication I am getting claims of the logged in user from the database as below.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginInputViewModel model)
{
 if (ModelState.IsValid)
 {
   //do authentication here
   //Once user is authenticated then go to next step

   //Below is the authorization part

   var userPermission = //getting all the permission from db

   List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
   foreach (var user in userPermission)
   {
      claims.Add(new Claim("Permission", user.Permission));
      claims.Add(new Claim("FirstName", user.FirstName));
      claims.Add(new Claim("LastName", user.LastName));
   }

    // create identity
    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "cookie");

   // create principal
   ClaimsPrincipal principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
   await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal);

 }
 else
 {
   this.ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid credentials.");                    
   return this.View(inputModel);
  } 
}
```

I have also my Base controller as:

```
 public class BaseController : Controller
  {
    public User LoggedInUser
    {
        get
        {
            return new User(this.User as ClaimsPrincipal);
        }
    }
  }
```

I am not showing all the code but above User returns all my claims ie FirstName, LastName & Permission

And I am using this base controller on my home as:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{

}
```

I want to setup authorization on my application. I already have permission in my claims (which returns Read or Write Permission). Based on these permission I want to show hide certain controls on my view. How can I do that. Or since I already have my claims in User which is in base controller how can I access that in my view. Or is there any better way to authorize controls on view.

Would appreciate inputs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can use Authorize attribute and [claims-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims)

Add policy in your ConfigureServices

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("FullAccessOnly", policy => policy.RequireClaim("FullAccess"));
});
```

And use this policy in your controllers

```
public IActionResult SomePage()
{
    return View();
}

[Authorize(Policy = "FullAccessOnly")]
public IActionResult SomePageWithFullAccess()
{
    return View();
}
```

2) or you can use one method where you will check claims and prepare viewmodel with FullAcess property

3) or get your claims in view

```
    @{ 
        var fullaccess = User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "Permission").FirstOrDefault().Value == "RW" ? true : false;
    }

@if(fullaccess){
//interface with fullacess
} else {
//interface with RO access
}
```